# Angular animate fails in production

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sails.js, ng-animate

I have a MEAN stack application using Sails.js as the starting point. I've used angular-animate and it works perfectly in developtment, but when changing Sails environment to production I get nada.

Grunt is configured to concatenate and minify all scripts and styles when in production environment and produce production.js and production.css

What I know:

- The `.ng-enter` class is not being added
- There are no errors in the console
- The scripts are in the correct order

What I've tried:

- Using production.js and production.css in development environment: works
- Commenting out Gruntfile and loading all scripts and styles individually in production environment: fails

What I don't understand:

- How can a server environment variable affect client-side javascript?

Thanks in advance. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Well I thought I had taken Grunt out of the equation, but alas. I had previously added code to my Gruntfile that autoprefixes my styles, and it was not included in the production Grunt task.

Apparently Angular does not fire animation events if it doesn't detect a CSS rule for them. I don't know this to be true for fact, but it appears to be that way.